# Primefaces Datatable and InputText element to create dynamic form

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I ve a question about using inputText element in primefaces datatable.

Xhtml is like below

```
<h:form >
                 <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:commandButton action="#{offerController.addNewOfferRow}" update="panel1" id="iconOnly1"  
           icon="ui-icon-circle-plus" value="Yeni Satır" title="Icon Add"  style="width:220px;" /> 


                 </h:panelGrid>
                <p:dataTable id="panel1" var="offer" value="#{offerController.offerIds}"  style="align: center;">
                    <p:column id="modelHeader"  style=" margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:70%;" >
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Eklenecek Offerlar
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:inputText id="addOfferId" value="#{offer}"   style=" margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:70%;"  />

                    </p:column>


                </p:dataTable>
```

And my java bean is like below:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped


public class OfferController implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1552493989687233258L;
    private static final int defaultNumberOfRows = 6;
    private List<String> offerIds = new LinkedList<String>();


    public OfferController() {
         super();
    for(int i=0;i<defaultNumberOfRows;i++){
        offerIds.add("");
         }

    }

    public void addOffers(){
         // do some op.
    }

    public void addNewOfferRow(){
         offerIds.add("");
    }

    public getOfferIds(){
         return offerIds;
    }

    public setOfferIds(List<String> offerIds){
          this.offerIds = offerIds;
    }


}
```

When using codes above.I want to display a list of string items in inputText elements which is in datatable.

And addNewOfferRow operation add new element to List and datatable is updated client side.

However after submitting the form all inputText elements does not store the values entered by user.

How can i use these datatable end inputText element to create dynamic rows form.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if your bean gets recreated on submit? Set a breakpoint inside the constructor to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a list of Strings (immutable type) which doesn't allow the inputText element to set the value on a list item.

Use a wrapper class containing a String as your list items.

```
<p:dataTable var="item" value="#{listBean.list}">
     <p:column>
         <p:inputText value="#{item.name}" />
     </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```